# Json data coming back null

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

Good evening, guys! I've got an odd one.

Long story short, I'm sending a post from a java script client-side to get an integer back from my C# Controller, but the response.data is coming back null. The twist is that both the C# method and the javascript/jquery function are literally copied and pasted from another project where both of them work. The project they're taken from is a VS2010 project, and they're pasted into a VS2012 project. I'm not sure if this is the issue, but it could be related. The integer is fetched correctly in the C# and none of the information is missing. Even more mysteriously, the success message is coming back correctly to the response object client-side. However the response.data object is null, and throws an exception.

Any and all help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

This is the method in the C#:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetMaxFileSize()
    {
        int MaxFileSize = 0;

        // Get max file size. 
        string MaxPatientFileSizeInMegsString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxFacilityLogoFileSizeInMegs"];
        MaxFileSize = int.Parse(MaxPatientFileSizeInMegsString);

        return Json(new AjaxResponse(true, "Success.", new { maxFileSize = MaxFileSize }));
    }
```

And this is the javascript/jquery function:

```
    function getMaxFileSize() {
        $.post(settings.actions.getMaxFileSize, function (response) {

            var maxFileSize = 0;

            // Assign the correct size to the hidden field.
            if (response.success) {
                maxFileSize = response.data.maxFileSize;
                $(settings.selectors.maxFileSizeHiddenInput).val(maxFileSize);
            }
            // Assign 0 to max file size: user cannot upload files.
            else {
                $(settings.selectors.maxFileSizeHiddenInput).val(maxFileSize);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine here!

TestController.cs

```
    public class AjaxResponse
    {
            public AjaxResponse(bool success, object data)
            {
                this.success = success;
                this.data = data;
            }
            public bool success { get; set; }

            public object data { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Ajax()
    {
        return Json(new AjaxResponse(true, new { num = 5 }));
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
    $.post('@Url.Action("Ajax", "Test")', function (response) {

        var num = 0;
        debugger;
        // Assign the correct size to the hidden field.
        if (response.success) {
            num = response.data.num;
            $('h2').html(num);
        }
            // Assign 0 to max file size: user cannot upload files.
        else {
            $('h2').html(num);
        }
    });
```

JSON response in FireBug:

```
    {"success":true,"data":{"num":5}}
```

Comment: Hi Shay. The structure of the AjaxResponse class in your answer gave me a clue as to what it was: the AjaxResponse class in my application (not built by me) was not assigning Data properly (Wasn't using 'this' and the argument coming in was the same name and casing as the object property, Data = Data). Essentially this always kept Data null. Thanks for your help!